# What is ndk.abiFilters doing under the hood?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, native, abi

I have some native libraries (.a) that I'm packaging into an Android library (AAR) as .so's, but they only support 32-bit and 64-bit ARM, so in my AAR's build.gradle defaultConfig, I have:

```
    ndk {

        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
```

And sure enough, my native .so's end up in the AAR under `<AAR>/jni/<ABI>/blah.so`

But when I add my AAR as a dependency for an APK, those .so's do not end up getting packaged into my APK.

UNLESS I also add the above *ndk* block to the defaultConfig of the APK's build.gradle.

Can anyone explain what is/isn't happening here? I like to distribute my AAR locally within my company, without requiring them to add that *ndk* block to their APK build.gradle files.

Comment: Does your APK's build.gradle have an `ndk` block in it anywhere currently?

Comment: @RyanM: No, it doesn't because the APK itself doesn't have any native code as part of its source, but it will depend on my AAR which will have native code.

At some point, I won't own the APK and won't have control over its build.gradle.  I'll just be distributing my AAR containing the native code.

Comment: `ndk.abiFilters` controls which ABIs the Android Gradle plugin should build and package native libraries for. According to the documentation, _"When this flag is not configured, Gradle builds and packages all available ABIs"_. One possible reason I can see for why that isn't happening in this case would be that the Android Gradle plugin wants to avoid situations where different modules support overlapping but different sets of native ABIs, and it wants you to be explicit about which ABIs you want to package in your APK. That's just me speculating though.